# Send-MailMessage - from parameter error?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send a mail using PowerShell  with below command:

```
powershell -command "& {Send-MailMessage -To "xxxxx@xx.com" -From "xxxx@domain.com" -SMTPServer xxx.xx.com -Subject "report" -Body "service is running"}"
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Send-MailMessage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'xxx@xx.com'.
At line:1 char:20
+ & {Send-MailMessage <<<<  -To "xxx@xx.com -From "xxx@xx.com -SMTPServer xxxx.xx.com -Subject "Daily report" -Body "service is running"}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Comment: You could try using APOSTROPHE characters around the command instead of QUOTE characters. Also, I'm not sure that you need an '&'.

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already mentioned, your quoting is broken. You're trying to nest double quotes inside a double-quoted string without escaping them. The unescaped nested double quotes prematurely terminate your string, causing the error you observed.

The simplest fix for this problem is to replace the nested double quotes with single quotes, since you don't seem to be using variables in that command anyway:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {Send-MailMessage -To 'xxxxx@xx.com' -From ..."
```

If you want to keep using nested double quotes (e.g. because you have variables in your scriptblock, which wouldn't be expanded in single-quoted strings) you need to escape them. If you're running the command from outside PowerShell (e.g. from CMD) you can do so by using backslashes:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {Send-MailMessage -To \"xxxxx@xx.com\" -From ..."
```

If you're running the command from within PowerShell you need to escape the nested double quotes twice (once for PowerShell when it's parsing the commandline, and once for the actual command invocation):

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {Send-MailMessage -To \`"xxxxx@xx.com\`" -From ..."
```

However, if you're actually running it from PowerShell you don't need the `powershell.exe -Command` in the first place. Just invoke `Send-MailMessage` directly:

```
Send-MailMessage -To "xxxxx@xx.com" -From ...
```

Comment: This is also a good case for encoding the command as well especially if it is for something simple like just sending a mail.